# Gnu plot: How do I draw a 2d surface on a domain which is not rectangular?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm really new to gnu.

I turned to gnu, because I couldn't get matlab to draw my surface.

How do I draw a 2d surface on a non-rectangular domain of values?

For example, I want to plot the following set

S = {z | x * y^2 =z  such that x + y <1  and x > 0 and y> 0}.

I think one solution would be to define a function

f(x,y) := x*y^2  whenever x+y <1, x>0 and y>0

f(x,y) := 100   else.

Then I can simply restrict the picture to the part that interest me.
But how do I define a piecewise function of two variables?

Help always appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `parametric` mode. This gives you are rectangular `(u, v)` domain, which you must transform appropriately to get your desired `(x, y)` domain:

```
set parametric
set urange [0:1]
set vrange [0:1]
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set view 62,24
set ticslevel 0
splot u, v*(1-u), u*v**2
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself!

Here's the solution

f(x,y) = x+y<= 1 ? 1 : 1/0
splot [0:1] [0:1] [0:4]\
f(x,y)*( MY FUNCTION).

So, basically, I defined a step function and multiplied everything by it.

Cheers